# How to format TestUnit diff output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I am using MiniTest out of the box with Rails 4 and the diff output looks kind of odd, and confusing. See the following output from a failed `assert_equal` (`assert_equal 5, someBigDecimalValue`)

```
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-5
+#<BigDecimal:7fa7db1dd528,'0.1E2',9(18)>
```

The expected result specified in the test was `5`, but the `-` character preceding it makes the expected result look like `-5`. The `@@ -1 +1 @@` part is also confusing.

Output looks fine when the expected value and the actual value are of the same type:

```
Expected: "Foo"
Actual: "Bar"
```

How can I get MiniTest to output the first test something like this:

```
Expected: 5
Actual: #<BigDecimal:7fa7db1dd528,'0.1E2',9(18)>
```